# Finding min and max point in a series

Tags: java

I got a series like this:

```
20 22 25 27 30 31 30 25 22 19 21  25 28 30 28 27...
```

As soon as the numbers reach near 30, they start moving negatively, and as soon as they reach near 20, they start moving positively.

I need to find these 2 points using some sort of algo. I'm totally lost.

I can't just do a sort because then I get 31 as max and 19 as min.

In real implementation, the numbers can change, and can be Float as well, instead of just int. It can be something like this:

```
55.20 57.35 54.30 59.25 61.00 58.20 55.40 53.50 58.75 60.10 55.15 53.40 50.00 51.10 52.00
```

In this case 53 and 60 are the points, and additionally, a third lower point 50.00.

How would I go ahead on this?

Comment: Define "reach". If you move left to right, and numbers decrease after 30, then why is there a 31 after a 30?

Comment: If you are looking for the minimum and the maximum points why are 19 and 31 bad results? Anyway you want to search not to sort.

Comment: 31 is bad because later in the series 30 appears again, and series goes negative without going to 31. I don't have any code yet because I can't even figure out the logic yet. All I've done so far is loaded them in a float array and staring at them... I don't need a code, just a pointer to move forward. Thanks :)

Comment: Thats why 31 is the maximum. Or tell us what kind of maximum are you looking for.

Comment: A first step would be to formalise what is a maximum - in your case it seems that you want an index `i` such that `array[i-1] < array[i]` and `array[i] > array[i+1]`. Once the definition is clear, the code should be easy enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetExtrema  {

  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> getExtrema(T[] series) {
    List<T> extrema = new ArrayList<T>();
    extrema.add(series[0]);
    boolean upElseDown = series[1].compareTo(series[0]) > 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < series.length; ++i) {
        if (series[i].compareTo(series[i-1]) > 0 != upElseDown) {
            extrema.add(series[i-1]);
            upElseDown = !upElseDown;
        } // end if
    } // end for
    extrema.add(series[series.length-1]);
    return extrema;
  } // end getExtrema()

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] s1 = {20,22,25,27,30,31,30,25,22,19,21,25,28,30,28,27};
    List<Integer> extrema = getExtrema(s1);
    System.out.println(extrema);

    Double[] s2 = {55.2,57.3,54.3,59.2,61.,58.2,55.4,53.5,58.7,60.1,55.1,53.4,50.,51.1,52.};
    List<Double> extrema2 = getExtrema(s2);
    System.out.println(extrema2);

    System.exit(0);

  } // end main()

} // end class GetExtrema
```

Compilation and execution:

```
javac GetExtrema.java;
CLASSPATH=. java GetExtrema;
## [20, 31, 19, 30, 27]
## [55.2, 57.35, 54.3, 61.0, 53.5, 60.1, 50.0, 52.0]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to what I want. Could you please explain these 2 points: What is "> 0" doing in this line series[1].compareTo(series[0]) > 0; 2. upElseDown = !upElseDown; What is this line doing? Thanks

Comment: 1. The snippet `series[1].compareTo(series[0]) > 0` is comparing if `series[1]` is greater than `series[0]`. The `> 0` test is specifically necessary as `compareTo()` returns -1, 0, or 1, and we must convert it to boolean for the purpose of detecting reversals (up-to-down or down-to-up) in the series direction. 2. The line `upElseDown = !upElseDown;` inverts the boolean variable `upElseDown` in response to a detection of such a reversal, thereby keeping it in line with the current direction of the series.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a homework assignment and you can use outside libraries, consider something like [Apache Commons StatUtils min function](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/StatUtils.html#min(double[])). There is a corresponding max function also. This particular library expects doubles, there should be something similar for floats.

If this is a homework assignment and the task at hand is to learn how to develop an algorithm, avoid sorting. It is not necessary. A simple loop and two tracking variables for min and max will do. For each iteration over the series, check the value and check if:

- the current value is less than min, if it is set min to the current value
- the current value is greater than max, if it set max to the current value

Comment: But won't that finally give me 19 and 31 as answer? Because 31 is the max here. However, the series is reverting at 30 later, without going to 31. So the answer should be 19 and 30